# Is there a way to delete a root in tkinter without stopping the program?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to make two roots and get rid of one in order to show the other one?

```
from tkinter import *
root1 = Tk()
root2 = Tk()
```

Because the first one is created first, it is on the top.
Is there a way to get rid of the first root1 to show root2?
root1.destroy doesn't work. I think it stops the whole program.

Comment: usually we use `root1.destroy()` or we could also use `root1.withdraw()` , which hides the root1 window then use `root1.iconify()` to bring it back. And are you not using `root1.mainloop()` and `root2.mainloop()`?

Comment: Why do you want to create two root windows? Why aren't you creating a single root window and then additional `Toplevel` windows?

Comment: @CoolCloud When I use root1.destroy(), the program freezes. I havn't tried root1.withdraw(), and I will take a look later. I am not using mainloop because I'm coding on repl which doesn't work with mainloop very well. I do have idle, so it is possible for me move my code if repl is not working.

Comment: @BryanOakley I had two mini-pieces of code I made before, and I want to combine them. I had a lot of labels/buttons/entries on there so it would be annoying to do them all (if I am not mistaken, you have to do Toplevel on every single widget.)

Comment: Do you need to share any tkinter objects between the two root windows, such as images or StringVars or widgets? It's generally a bad practice to have more than one root window, since the objects created in one can't be used in the other.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok, I won't do that next time, but there is no widgets, images, etc. that I need use in both root windows. I will just do root1.withdraw() for now.